# How to plot average line for a month in a Python for loop?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, average

I have code which looks something like this:

```
for _, d in Country_sim_count.set_index('Week').groupby('Home_Country'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    d['SIM_total'].plot()
    plt.axhline(y=d['SIM_total'].mean(), color='r', linestyle='--') #the line I would like to alter
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title(f"Weekly Sim Count for {d['Home_Country'].iat[0]}")
    plt.xlabel('Week')

    a = '2020-01-13' #Key dates area
    b = '2020-02-10'

    plt.axvspan(a, b, color='gray', alpha=0.2, lw=0)
    plt.legend()
    #plt.savefig(f"{d['Home_Country'].iat[0]}_plot.png")
    plt.show()
```

The dataframe contains various months however on Line 4 I wanted to plot a red line which would show the average calculated for only February per country, instead of calculating the mean for all the months combined. The feb average will be different for each country in the loop.
Currently my plot looks like this:

[image]

The value for the red line is the average combined from Jan-May however I'm hoping to have the red line value show the average value for Feb throughout.

Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try including a condition inside the brackets?

```
plt.axhline(y=d[d['SIM_total'] == 'February'].mean(), color='r', linestyle='--')
```

I hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

In that case I think it would be better not to set 'Week' as the index.

Thou it may not very pretty, you could use something like the code below.

```
feb_mean = d[d['Week'] == 'February']['SIM_total'].mean()

plt.axhline(y=feb_mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Hi there, thank you however the Feb values are in a column called "Week" and the values from Sim Total are the counts that I need in order to calculate the averages. Is there a way I can include the 'week' column as a filter?

Comment: In my dataframe, the Weeks are in the format  '2020-02-11' -> How can I run your code to filter dates within the Feb month based on this format? :)

Comment: Also, when I don't set the 'Week' as the index, the x-axis does not show any dates however I need them to show

Comment: Hi R Sem. That's because when you use "d['SIM_total'].plot()", by default the index is set as the x axis, thou you can change it. Maybe you could use sns.lineplot(). Here you have the docs: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html
On the other hand, it really doesn't matter the format of the dates, as long as your program recognizes it as a date!